# convert string having html image tag into image using TextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(string))

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a string which as follows:

```
String text = "<img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png">"
```

When I do

```
TextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

I need the image to be displayed in the activity.

**I do not want to use a WebView.**

Please let me know as to what are the other ways to achieve this.

Comment: You want to set the URL in a `TextView` or extract the URL, fetch the image and display in an `ImageView`

Comment: @Santhosh V M what's wrong in using WebView

Comment: @SiddharthLele I don't want to use an imageView. The string which I pass sometimes will not have html image tag in them.

Comment: @SantoshVM: And will the tags change too?

Comment: Try using imagegetter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the idea in these below links.

http://www.docstoc.com/docs/120417139/How-To-Implement-Htmlfromhtml-With-Imagegetter-In-Android

http://shiamiprogrammingnotes.blogspot.com/2010/09/textview-with-html-content-with-images.html

Answer (score 1):

you have to use asynctask,open connection in `doInbackground()` set image to textview in `onPostExecute()`

```
try {
        /* Open a new URL and get the InputStream to load data from it. */
        URL aURL = new URL("ur Image URL");
        URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
        conn.connect();
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        /* Buffered is always good for a performance plus. */
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        /* Decode url-data to a bitmap. */
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
        bis.close();
        is.close();

        Drawable d =new BitmapDrawable(bm);
       d.setId("1");
 textview.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,0,1,0);// wherever u want the image relative to textview
        } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("error", "Remote Image Exception", e);
        }
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your text in `strings.xml`

```
<string name="nice_html">
<![CDATA[<img src='https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png'>
]]></string>
```

Then, in your code:

```
TextView foo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.foo); 
foo.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.nice_html)));
```